# Different ways of comparing strings

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements, equals

I was browsing through code on Github, and I found that someone uses this way to compare 2 strings.

```
if ("whatever".equals(theString))
```

Is there any difference between the normal way of comparing strings

```
if (theString.equals("whatever"))
```

and the way above?

I am not sure if a similar question has been asked before, if yes, I apologize.

Comment: `theString.equals("whatever")` can throw NullPointerException. `"whatever".equals(theString)` can't.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ;)

Comment: [Yoda notation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/1003/nullpointerexception/12297/using-yoda-notation-to-prevent-npes#t=201608090726261343276) called this is.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-

Comment: @Jeremy This question like pretty much any questions you can come up with have been asked *and* answered hundreds of times. Learn to search for information.

Comment: @Kayaman It is hard because the best title I could think of was "different ways of comparing strings".

Comment: @Jeremy Yeah, the SO search functionality is shit, but if you can't learn to find information even when it doesn't jump right at you, how do you think you'll learn something as complex as programming.

Answer (score 7):

`if("whatever".equals(theString))` 
has the advantage that if `theString` is `null` you won't hit a `NullPointerException`. The rest is the same.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed by others, Yoda notation is used to avoid possible NPE. However, I don't really think it's an advantage to hide a potential bug in your code.

Using

```
"whatever".equals(theString)
```

will not throw NPE, but you might thing that everything works as expected. Think about a situation where you failed to initialize your string, and it got `null`, your code won't break and the condition will be evaluated to false.

If `null` indicates something, you should check it and handle it appropriately:

```
if (theString == null) {
    // log, initialize or whatever
}
```